# Group Entire Crystal Report by Column in Subreport

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am trying to set up the following report so that it is grouped first by "Transfer-In Unit" (`d1_10.xinstitute`), which is the title of a column that is included in a sub-report, and second by `xpid`, which is a patient index number used in all tables (except a catalog) in this report. To simplify this question, assume that `xpid` is indexed in alphabetical order of the patients' names.
See info/examples below:

---

This report shows patients that have transferred out of a specific unit since the user-inputted date (`Name`), a row for each date that the patient transferred out of a particular unit (`Unit M Transfer-Out Date`), chronologically where they next transferred into (`Transfer-In Unit`), and when they transferred into that unit (`Transfer-In Date`).

Currently without attempting this grouping the output looks like this:

[image: Current Output]

- `Name` and `Unit M Transfer-Out Date` are on the parent report
- `Transfer-In Unit` and `Transfer-In Date` are **in a subreport** because they both call `d1_10.dstartdate` but with different criteria.

**The goal is to sort by `Transfer-In Unit`, which is a column in the subreport.**

The output should be:

[image: Desired Output]

An underlying issue is that to select the chronological next transfer-in following a transfer-out, I **have to select a minimum transfer date grouped by `xpid`**. This causes the requirement of an `xpid` grouping in the sub-report.

I have tried a grouping by `d1_10.xinstitute` (the unit index) in both the parent- and sub-reports. In the parent report it creates one all-encompassing group, because every row in this report represents someone transferring out of "Unit M". In the subreport it seems to apply the groupings row by row, so each row has two groups, even when the next row is the same patient transferring into the same unit. However this is my best attempt and it looks like this:

[image: Best Attempt Output]

Any help/thoughts/ideas much appreciated. Let me know if I can provide any further info.

Thanks

Comment: What is your exact requirement..group by unit or date?

Comment: Grouping by unit first, patient ID second. The date comes into play when selecting the transfer-in that follows each respective transfer-out. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I wouldn't try to relate the two reports, I'd have them as 2 independent pulls from the same data source.  So they'd both be sibling subreports instead of parent/child report.

Comment: @Beth That's an interesting idea, I'll try that. So then if I have two subreports, both with two columns, will this allow me to sort the total 4-column report by a column of one subreport? I'll give it a shot in the meantime

Comment: you can't sort the column of one sub report using the column of another sub report... as per your explain I understood that you want to sort your report with 2 columns simultaneously, Correct? is this you are asking?

Comment: I want to group the entire report by one column in the sub report, the `Transfer-In Unit` column. Each of these groupings then needs to be in order of patient so that if there are, for example, four rows for a patient Bob all transferring into Unit A, these rows are NOT split up by patient Charlie that is also transferring into Unit A

Comment: @Beth "Sibling reports" had the same problem. Thanks in advance for any new ideas

Comment: @Jackson, not sure what you were thinking, but the 'sibling' approach doesn't create one 4-column report, it has 2 2-column reports sorted by different criteria, which is what I thought you wanted.  First report sorted by xfer out, 2nd by xfer in.  Are you saying your 2nd report needs to be sorted by xfer in within the 1st report sorted by xfer out?

Comment: The rows cannot be mixed up, if row 1 of Sibling2 is sorted then the columns from Sibling1 need to sort with them, so I cannot sort each subreport separately, they are dependent

Comment: I'm working on a different approach, I'll post back with either an answer or further questions. Thanks for the help